# how to pass global variable in view to controller angularjs

Tags: angularjs, express, ejs

I'm tring to send backend by ejs to the frontend , controller of angularjs

**app.js**

i pass data to view/indexcontens.

```
var users = [
  {
    name: 'john',
    email: 'john@email.com'
  },
  {
    name: 'peter',
    email: 'peter@email.com'
  },
  {
    name: 'max',
    email: 'max@email.com'
  }
];

app.get('/partials/indexContents.html', function(req, res) {
  res.render('partials/indexContents', {users:users})
});
app.get('/partials/about.html', function(req, res) {
  res.render('partials/about')
});
```

**views/partials/indexContents**

 i made it global variable.

```
  <div>
    <h3>home</h3>
    <p>wecome to my blog. I hope you enjoy the content!</p>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="post in blogposts">{{post}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
        <script>
             users = "<%=abc=users[0].name%>";
        </script>
```

**public/js/contollers.js**
 trying to get the global variable

```
var app= angular.module('blog',['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    //set up routes
    $routeProvider
    .when('/home',{
        templateUrl:'partials/indexContents.html',
        controller:'SimpleController'
    })
    .when('/about',{
        templateUrl:'partials/about.html',
        controller:'AboutController'
    })      
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo:'/'
    });
});


app.controller('SimpleController', function($scope){

    $scope.blogposts=[
    'blog post1',
    'blog post2',
    window.users
    ];
}); 


app.controller('AboutController', function($scope){
    $scope.name="graum";
    $scope.bio="i just made it";
});
```

but it only display blank instead of 'john'.

Please give me a solution, thank you

Comment: Are you interested in encapsulating the data in a service perhaps?

Comment: @user3713746 take a look at my answer

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use $resource to get the name from server? I know this is not the best option and certainly not what you are looking for but this way it works for sure.
however you can try this too

```
<script>
         (function() {users = "<% users[0].name%>";})();
</script>
```